# C# WPF обработчик скрывать и открывать кнопки

Tags: c#, wpf

На форме есть `Select`, при выборе какого-нибудь пункта `Items` например: "Сложить 3 числа", на форме должно появляться 3 `textBox` и `Button`. 
Если в `Select` выбираю "Сложить 5 чисел", то появляется 5 `textBox` и `Button`, и т.д.
 Как реализовать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вешайте обработчик на изменение в Select-e (или кнопка у Вас будет типа "Применить" - тут уж неважно). Далее создаете массив из N объектов типа textBox, каждому назначаете позицию на форме (здесь нужно грамотно продумать это, чтобы не "поползло"), ну кнопка одна - тут все понятно. А потом значения из TextBox-ов вытаскивать в цикле по массиву.